# Why does intent not require ActivityNotFound exception?

Tags: java, android, exception, android-activity

I noticed something that seems a bit strange in Android: Calls to start an activity intent *could* throw an ActivityNotFound exception, if the expected app/handler is not installed, but there is no warning when coding this. When writing file reading/writing, network, etc. code, it usually gives a warning, you must either mark this function as "throws exception", or add a try/catch for certain exceptions. Why are activity intents different?

Furthermore, if I mark a function as "throws ActivityNotFoundException", I can still make a caller that doesn't catch this error, it compiles fine and gives no warning. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason no warning is given is because [`ActivityNotFoundException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html) extends `RuntimeException` which does not have to be checked. The reason Google uses this is, as @Rocky Triton said, because it's a massive pain for developers to have to check every single statement that *could* throw an exception. While [Java discourages this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), it still saves developers a huge hassle. (I even hate having to catch I/O exceptions...)

Comment: In some situations (calling *your own* intents) it is not needed. This may be why they did it that way?

Comment: Potentially, yes. It's hard to understand the motive behind it, but I'd guess that they do have reasons for most of them, in addition to the fact that they'd rather we were debugging instead of `catch`ing everything.

Answer (score 2):

Because forcing unchecked exceptions is horrible, I'm glad google doesn't make you.